# [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Driver's SQLSetConnectAttr failed vb6

Tags: vb6, connection, odbc

I had this application source and I moved from w7 32 to w7 64. Code is in vb6. It was working well on 32 bit machine, but now get this error. `[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Driver's SQLSetConnectAttr failed` But strange thing is if I compile on 64 bit then .exe runs and connects to oracle with no problem. But if I try to debug it - it gives me error. I found odbc driver for 64bit but could not download it. Can someone give idea what to do? Odbc source is correct in C:\Windows\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe

Comment: What ODBC driver are you using? Not much that can be done without showing the code that causes the problem.

Also note, all apps written in VB6 are 32-bit (regardless of whether they are compiled on a 64-bit OS) and therefore you would want the 32-bit ODBC driver, not 64-bit.

Comment: Does your VB6 app connect to ODBC via DAO or ADODB?

Answer (score 4):

Try setting the ODBC up (on the 64bit pc)for 32 bit too. the one that you get too via: >contol panel >administrative tools >Data sources (ODBC) see if that works.